# How do loop custom module

Tags: terraform

I had a `main.tf` custom TF module, the module will deploy a lists of another custom modules. I can deploy single region by passing single value into `main.tf`, but when I tried multi-region which passing an array of regions and loop in `main.tf`'s custom module. It doesn't work.

**main.tf**

```
locals {
  regions = ["asia-east2", "asia-southeast1"]
}

module "main" {
  source = "./modules/main"
  for_each = local.regions
  region = each.value
}
```

**Error:**

> The name "for_each" is reserved for use in a future version of Terraform.`

**Notes**

I know Terraform 0.12 doesn't support this feature. Is there a way to loop through multi-region **without passing down into child module's resource level** ?

Comment: The error implies you are not on one of the versions of Terraform that supports iteration in this way.

Comment: You are correct, Terraform (even v0.12) doesn't support the `for_each` attribute for Modules.  So what you are asking to do is not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

> I know Terraform 0.12 doesn't support this feature. Is there a way to loop through multi-region without passing down into child module's resource level ?

No. There is no way to loop through `local.regions` and pass them into modules in Terraform 0.12 because [`count`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html) and [`for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) for modules were added in Terraform 0.13.

Your only option is to make multiple references.

```
locals {
  regions = ["asia-east2", "asia-southeast1"]
}

module "main_0" {
  source = "./modules/main"
  region = local.regions[0]
}

module "main_1" {
  source = "./modules/main"
  region = local.regions[1]
}
```

Note that it's better to instantiate the provider at the root level with an alias and pass in the provider alias to each module instead of instantiating the provider inside the module.